# Is it possible to use LESS with CSS on a CDN?

Tags: html, css

I am using a Bootswatch theme, for example `Readable`.

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is it possible to use the `variables.less` file even though the main CSS is hosted on a CDN?

For example I want to change the font

`@font-family-sans-serif:  "Raleway", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the css file on the CDN is precompiled with the default variables embedded.

If you wish to override only a few styles then just include your own css file after the cdn-hosted one with your modifications. E.g.

```
body {
    font-family: "Raleway", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

This will override the ones in the original bootstrap file.

If you are making more extensive modifications then I'd advise to downloading the less source files and recompile with your changes. You can then have the resultant css file hosted on a CDN of your choice for enhanced performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but [convert your LESS to CSS at build time](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage) and publish plain CSS to the CDN.

Doing it client side is likely to run in the [Same Origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) issues when trying to read the data from the remotely hosted file.

Comment: This is what we do where I work. Though I should mention, we don't touch the variables.less file, or any Bootstrap files for that matter. Doing so can give you a headache when it comes time to upgrade. I'd recommend just overriding.

Answer (score 1):

LESS in only preprocessor that creates CSS files. So users should have served only CSS files and not LESS or SASS files. And those CSS you can then serve in CDN

Comment: That isn't entirely true. You can [use LESS in the browser](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser) (but doing what with a CDN can be problematic).

Comment: I didn't know it's possible. I use SASS (as beginner) and I thought in LESS is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can but you need a converter LESS to CSS